# Api Mercado Pago - Inconsistencia en /collections/search

Tags: mercadopago

La API de Mercado Pago no está devolviendo datos cuando se le indica el parámetro **external_reference**.

Probando lo siguiente por consola:

```
/collections/search?external_reference=2016-11-renovar-abono-7761&range=date_created&begin_date=2016-10-01T00%3A00%3A00.000-03%3A00&end_date=2017-02-01T23%3A59%3A59.000-03%3A00&offset=0&limit=0&access_token=[eltoken]
```

Devuelve:

```
    {
    "paging": {
        "total": 4,
        "limit": 0,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "results": []
}
```

Esta llamada debería devolver al menos un movimiento y la prueba de ello se da cuando ejecuto lo mismo pero **sin external_reference**:

```
/collections/search?range=date_created&begin_date=2016-10-01T00%3A00%3A00.000-03%3A00&end_date=2017-02-01T23%3A59%3A59.000-03%3A00&offset=0&limit=0&access_token=[eltoken]
```

Devuelve:

```
    {
    "paging": {
        "total": 1,
        "limit": 10,
        "offset": 0
    },
    "results": [{
        "collection": {
            "id": 2471392144,
            "site_id": "MLA",
            "date_created": "2016-12-01T13:27:58.000-04:00",
            "date_approved": null,
            "last_modified": "2016-12-01T13:29:12.000-04:00",
            "money_release_date": null,
            "operation_type": "regular_payment",
            "collector_id": 78381283,
            "sponsor_id": null,
            "payer": { ... },
            "external_reference": "2016-11-renovar-abono-7761",
            ...
        }
    }]
}
```

**¿Como puedo hacer que el resultado devuelva el external_reference?**

**Editado**

- Utilizando el SDK para PHP versión 0.5.2
- Método $api->search_payment
- La uri que genera dicho método es /collections/search?external_reference=2016-11-renovar-abono-7761&range=date_created&begin_date=2016-10-03T00%3A00%3A00.000-03%3A00&end_date=2017-02-03T23%3A59%3A59.000-03%3A00&offset=0&limit=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrado el problema, hay inconsistencia en el manejo del parámetro **limit** cuando se indica o no **external_reference**.

Si no aclaramos el parámetro **limit**, el SDK PHP 0.5.2 le asigna por defecto el valor 0 (cero), el cual yo interpreto como "sin límite".

Ahora, si dicho parámetro es 0 y especificamos un **external_reference** podemos ver en la salida que **paging** tiene **limit = 0**, en cambio si no especificamos **external_reference** la salida devuelve **limit = 10**.

Dado que hasta hace poco siempre devolvía resultados sin aclarar el limit, supongo que hicieron algún cambio en la API y ahora el parámetro limit se interpreta diferente.

Answer (score -1):

Al parecer no tienes ese pago registrado, quizas lo hiciste usando un access_token de test o estas trabajando en sandbox, y la búsqueda la realizas sobre producción, el siguiente request:

[/collections/search?begin_date=2015-2-2T00:00:00.001-04:00&end_date=2017-2-2T23:59:59.999-04:00&access_token=[eltoken]&external_reference=**500-1423-1-1-NTAw**](http://#)

Devuelve:

```
{
    "paging": {
        "limit": 30,
        "offset": 0,
        "total": 1
    },
    "results": [
       {
         "collection": {
           ...
           "external_reference": "500-1423-1-1-NTAw"
           ...
         ]
    }
}
```

Por lo que entiendo, que la búsqueda por `external_reference` si la esta realizando.

Comment: Si ese fuera el caso, entonces la segunda consulta no me devolvería nada en lugar de devolverme una colección con el pago de external_reference igual a "2016-11-renovar-abono-7761".

Fijate que la segunda consulta es exactamente la misma (mismo token, probada en la misma consola rest), pero sin el parámetro external_reference y me está devolviendo lo que debería devolver la primera.

Comment: Además, agrego que dicha funcionalidad estuvo procesando cientos de pagos sin inconvenientes y no hubo cambios en el código del sistema cuando empezó el inconveniente.

Comment: Tenes razón, disculpa la omisión de la aclaración del error en tu pregunta, acabo de realizar una consulta usando el collector_id que mencionas 78381283, la respuesta que me da con el external_reference es de un total de 4 registros, podrias validar nuevamente la búsqueda ? proba con esta url reemplazando el token al final https://api.mercadolibre.com/collections/search?collector_id=78381283&begin_date=2015-2-2T00:00:00.001-04:00&end_date=2017-2-2T23:59:59.999-04:00&range=date_created&external_reference=2016-11-renovar-abono-7761&access_token=[eltoken]

Comment: Joel, gracias por la respuesta. Añadí más información y comparé tu url con la que generaba la api y encontré el problema y la solución. Lo dejo como respuesta más abajo.